Error while compiling and running spring boot project in intellij and vscode
Error while compiling and running spring boot project in intellij and vscode
press here to see the error
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-parseable POM E:\sbalacha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-parent-3.3.0.pom: Expected root
element 'project' but found 'html' (position: START_TAG seen ...tp://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="no-js" xml:lang="en" lang="en">... @3:82)  @ E:\sbalacha\.m2\repository\org\springframework\boot\spring-boot-starter-parent\3.3.0\spring-boot-starter-parent-3.3.0.pom, line 3, column 82
Getting this error while i run the spring boot project in intellij and vs code.
i have installed maven 3.9.8, java 17 and spring boot version 3.3.0
why this error occurs? Can anyone help on this?

Two things.  First, don't post images to stack overflow.  Second, it looks like the spring-boot-starter-parent dependency is screwed up.  delete your maven dependencies and redownload them

that works, thanks @lane.maxwell

I found this issue. I have ran maven for my other projects a few days back and I used older version. So that older version dependencies are stored as a cache in .m2 folder. That the thing causing this issue. I deleted the .m2 folder and reran the spring-boot project, it downloaded the latest dependencies and got compiled successfully.
